# word constraints in routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

```
match '/posts/:id/:title' => 'posts#show', :as => :slug
resources :posts
```

I don't want slug_path to match some words as title parameter. 
For example:

```
posts/5/edit
```

"edit" is making trouble. I want to restrict this word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only worried about the standard routes interfering (like `edit`), simply put your `match` statement after your `resources :posts`. That way, the match statement will only catch anything that the resources statement didn't know how to handle.

Comment: will_paginate generates this url: posts/1?page=2&slugs=hello-world,  if i put match statement after resources :posts

Answer (score 0):

You can also [use a regular expression as a constraint to limit what :title can match](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints).  Another option would also be to make your URL more explicit - this would also avoid confusion with the default restful actions:

```
match '/posts/:id/title/:title' => 'posts#show', :as => :slug
```